# How can I transform a list with a class into clickable links without changing the text design?

Tags: html, css, button

I'm trying to do a word changer so I used a list with a class inside, but I want to click on the words that are changing. I've tried StackOverflow and Google but I didn't find anything.

```
<ul class="content__container__list">
    <li class="content__container__list__item">Select a Language !</li>
    <li class="content__container__list__item">Escolha um Idioma !</li>
    <li class="content__container__list__item">Sélectionnez une langue !</li>
    <li class="content__container__list__item">Selecciona un idioma !</li>
</ul>
```

I'm expecting that someone can tell me what do I need to do with my code to make one of the items in the list clickable (for redirecting me like a link!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add [`<a>`-tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) and the following [CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp). Click **Run code snippet** to see the result:

```css
.content__container__list__item > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  /*cursor: default;  <-- enable if you also want the cursor to stay the same*/
}
```

```html
<ul class="content__container__list">
    <li class="content__container__list__item"><a href="#">Select a Language !</a></li>
    <li class="content__container__list__item"><a href="#">Escolha um Idioma !</a></li>
    <li class="content__container__list__item"><a href="#">Sélectionnez une langue !</a></li>
    <li class="content__container__list__item"><a href="#">Selecciona un idioma !</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

To direct the text to another page — use the [`a` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp).

```
<ul class="content__container__list">
    <li class="content__container__list__item"><a href="#">Select a Language !</a></li>
    <li class="content__container__list__item"><a href="#">Escolha um Idioma !</a></li>
    <li class="content__container__list__item"><a href="#">Sélectionnez une langue !</a></li>
    <li class="content__container__list__item"><a href="#">Selecciona un idioma !</a></li>
</ul>
```

Or if you wanted a drop-down menu — see the [`select` and `option` HTML tags](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp).